# Are redux reducer cases neccessary?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

As title says, are they neccessary for every case, don't actions and effects(`ngrx`) do everything. ?

I have, for example, load, load-success action and that's it. I use 'load' action just for loading spinner..

I searched for articles about that but I couldn't find it, if you have some articles about this, please leave it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a really good question ... but for whatever reason, the powers that be here reject any type of "opinion-based" question that does not have a single "correct" answer. I would truly value a discussion on this topic ... wish there was *somewhere* to go to have these discussions.

Comment: Agree, I don't know why people spend time on reviewing someone else's post, we are here to help each other, to learn something.

Comment: If you want to have a broad discussion, try this: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: If your actions and effects do all the work and never reach a reducer, they don't need to be what they are in the first place. They could just be any async function doing what you want. Reducer cases are necessary because that's where you actually change the application state. But if your actions don't affect application state you obviously don't need a reducer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the very important part in ngrx is the reducer itself because I how you represent the data that you want you have. In my opinion the level of importance in this library is

1. Reducer // control the structure of your data and execute the changes necesarys
2. Actions // pass the new data and describe the kind of action you want to execute over the current data storaged
3. Effects // Execute all kind of side effects, and call others reducer actions

actually your app can exist without effects